# nodejs pipe or fs.rename FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: node.js, file, out-of-memory, fatal-error

Interesting. Some large file got error. Some does not.

Those file created by the following cmd does work.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/name/testfile.tar.gz bs=280M count=1
```

But some exe file does not work.

test.js

```
var source  = fs.createReadStream(req.files.file.path);
var dest    = fs.createWriteStream('/var/www/uploads/' + process.hrtime()[0] + process.hrtime()[1] + '_' + req.files.file.name);

source.pipe(dest);

source.on('end', function() { /* copied */ 
  console.log('end');
});

source.on('error', function(err) { /* error */ 
  console.log(err);
  console.log('error');
});
```

OR

```
fs.rename(req.files.file.path, '/var/www/name/uploads/' + process.hrtime()[0] + process.hrtime()[1] + '_' + req.files.file.name, function(err) {
  if(err)
    console.log(err);
  else
    console.log('file moved');
});
```